# Middleaware Admin redirection authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I created a middleware to check if a user is admin or editor, but for some reason in my if statement when i use the OR operator to check if the user has access, it doesnt work, it accepts the first property statement, but not after the OR operator.

To work i need to separate each condition of account type.

For example:

Code dont work:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if(Auth::user()->account_type_id == '1' || Auth::user()->account_type_id == '2') // is an admin
            {
                return $next($request); // pass the admin
            }


        return redirect('/admin'); // not admin. redirect whereever you like
    }
```

Code that Works:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      // dd($request->all());
            if(Auth::user()->account_type_id == '1') // is an admin
            {
                return $next($request); // pass the admin
            }

        if(Auth::user()->account_type_id == '2') // is an admin
            {
                return $next($request); // pass the admin
            }


        return redirect('/admin'); // not admin. redirect whereever you like
    }
```

Does anybody no whats wrong?

Comment: What about `if((Auth::user()->account_type_id == '1') || (Auth::user()->account_type_id == '2'))`?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array and check the condition again the array of possible solutions.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      $accountTypes = array('1','2');

      if (in_array(Auth::user()->account_type_id, $accountTypes)) {
        return $next($request); // pass the admin
      }

        return redirect('/admin'); // not admin
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`in_array`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function, this will also make your code more readable and easy to maintain.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (in_array(Auth::user()->account_type_id, ['1', '2'])) // is an admin
    {
        return $next($request); // pass the admin
    }

    return redirect('/admin'); // not admin. redirect whereever you like
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the second one work but here is mine and it works fine give it a try

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $user = $request->user();
    if ($user->role == 1 || $user->role == 2) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else{
    return redirect(url('/admin'));
    }
}
```